# What if this was a "Portable Virtual Computer"

Tags: us20050280786

In reference to the patent application: [US20050280786](https://www.google.com/patents/US20050280786)

What if this was a "Portable Virtual Computer", but still had a projector and computer (and battery) inside in one unit. Would this be legal.

Like this

[image: Like This]
[image: And this]

Answer (score 1):

The document you've linked to is a patent application, not a granted patent (now reflected in the edited question). You can see this in the box in the upper right of the Google patents page, where it says "Publication type: Application".

If you're interested in seeing the current state of the application, go to the USPTO's [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site and search for application number 10/872,492. In this case, it says "Status: Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action", meaning that this application has been abandoned and so it will never become a patent.

Nothing can infringe the application you've referred to.

Comment: @PolarComputers, could you please clarify what sort of answer you are looking for? You asked if the device would be legal. I can't answer that in general, but I did address possible infringement of the '786 patent you referred to in your question.

Comment: @PolarComputers: By the way, I didn't find the term "Portable Virtual Computer" in the patent, so I'm not certain what you meant by that. Are you suggesting that its being a "Portable Virtual Computer" is what makes it not a desktop computer? That line of reasoning could possibly be relied upon to argue that it would not infringe the patent. However, please note that just being "transportable by a single person" would not be enough to work around the cited patent (the patent makes it clear that such desktops are protected, as are ones that are not transportable like that).

Comment: Thank you, I also heard something about that patents expire do know when this one expires, I couldn't find a place where it says that

Comment: @PolarComputers, in looking for the answer to your follow-up question, I realized that this was not a granted patent. I've edited my answer accordingly. However, if this were a granted patent, it would expire 20 years after the priority date (shown in Google patents as Jun 22, 2004).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to the prosecution history of the patent application. Click on the "Espacenet" link, then "Global Dossier", you would see a history of the [patent examination](https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.87249204.A&lng=en). The application has been abandoned.

If you click on "Final Rejection" dated 26.01.2006, you would see that the claims were rejected because they were anticipated by [US20020030790](https://www.google.com.tw/patents/US20020030790), which at the time also was a application. The application was later granted as [US6626543](https://www.google.com.tw/patents/US6626543) "Electronic image projection device." Notably the claims in the granted patent contain limitation not present in the original draft, such as that the projector can be "docked" or that a keyboard is included. The patent has lapse due to non-payment of maintenance fee. However, I doubt the patent, if still active, would value much in a market dominated by tablets.

A "mere" combination of a new type of computer (e.g. a tablet or a portable virtual computer) would be deemed as obvious and would not be issued a utility patent (design patent, however, is another story). For such combination to be patentable, the invention must include additional inventive steps not disclosed by prior art.